# Opencv plugin call functions in unity3d

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, dll, unity-game-engine

I' am trying to create a plugin for my Unity Project based on OpenCV. I created the dll file target (based on visual C++ 2010 Express project).
The problem that when I try to call a function (using opencv) from the dll in my c# script, Unity crashes without displaying errors.
this is a test example of function that displays the number of an image's channels:

```
extern "C"
{
int EXPORT_API PrintChannelsNumber(std::string image){
Mat im = imread(image);
int s=im.channels();
return s;
}
}
```

in Unity :

```
[DllImport ("dllOpencvUnity")]
private static extern int PrintChannelsNumber(string s);
void Start () {
Debug.Log(PrintChannelsNumber("c:/photo.jpg"));
}
```

My question is what could be the problem and how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: please share the code